# How to get the first element in the collection with appcmd.exe?

Tags: iis, appcmd

I need to get recycling time for the app pool.
I can't use the powershell, so I use appcmd.exe for this. I found that there is a command for this:

```
%windir%\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe  LIST APPPOOL test /text:recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.[value='08:23:00'].value
```

But the problem that I need to specify the time to receive that time:
[image]

So now it works as a check if recycling has been scheduled for that specific time.
I suppose appcmd works with this data as a collection. Is there any way to get the first item?

Answer (score 0):

Below command will show you the IIS application pool config setting:

```
APPCMD LIST APPPOOL "sample1" /config
```

or

```
%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\APPCMD list apppool "sample1" /text:*
```